# Can I trigger a complete web page reload with content from a javascript string?

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is one of those ajax "alternate flow" questions. Normally I expect my ajax request to return a part of the page. But sometimes it may return a full page with html, head and body tag.

At the time I return from my ajax-request I can detect if this is a full page, but is it possible to trigger a full page reload (with full event cycle) based on the string content I have ?

(And yes, I have tried replacing the body element, but that does not give me the events and does not allow me to change the content in the head block)

Any framework reference is ok

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just generate the new HTML on the server, and sending an AJAX reply back, telling to load a new page at a specified URL?

Comment: If im hammering a nail with a hammer, can i suddenly use my hammer as a screwdriver? Tools have uses, when you through bad design try to use them for the opposite of their intended useage, you are bound to get into this sort of problems.

Comment: Reality bites. The redirect soultion coupled with an additional header is the more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do directly.

You'd be better off saving the HTML somewhere and sending back a URL where it can be retrieved, then using `location.href = ...`;

Answer (score 2):

You can decide what to do with your [AJAX request](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request) based on it's [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

If you get 301 ("moved permanently") you could do a redirect using `window.location`:

```
new Ajax.Request(url, {
  method: 'get',
  // status 200: yadaa
  onSuccess: function(transport) {
    // doSomething
  },
  // status 301: moved permanently
  on301: function(transport){ 
    window.location = transport.responseText;
  }
});
```

Comment: This sounds good, especially if I use an additional header field in the 302 to indicate full page redirect.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work, since 301/302 does not seem to reach prototype (its handled by the browser and never reaches javascript).

Answer (score 0):

At least in *Firefox*, you can use the [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) property. The *location* object 
contains information about the URL of the document and provides methods for changing that URL. You can also assign to this property to load another URL.

An example from the doc:

```
Replace the current document with the one at the given URL:

function goMoz() { 
   window.location = "http://www.mozilla.org";
} 

// in html: <button onclick="goMoz();">Mozilla</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

window.location = "same-url-as-im-at.aspx";

...?

To do it with an HTML document directly I'd *desperately* try to avoid if I were you for reasons you have skimmed in your original question...